# Moving existing docker image to Azure

Tags: azure, docker

We have an existing docker container which is running an dotnet core website. Requirement is to move this container to Azure and run website over cloud. 
All tutorials or Howtos point at creating new docker image.Can someone provide me a link or direction to achieve this requirement.

Comment: Check this blog on how to publish a containerizeed .NET Core app to Azure. https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/webdev/2016/11/16/new-docker-tools-for-visual-studio/
If it doesn't satisfy your condition, how does your setup differ from whats demonstrated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just push the image to a docker repository that is accesible externally and pull the image from there. Depending on what you use (vms\webapp\container instances) procedures for pulling will be different. For vm's - regular procedure, for webapps - [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service/containers/tutorial-custom-docker-image) for container instances - [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/container-instances/container-instances-quickstart-portal)

Comment: will that be safe. I mean Docker repositories are public in nature, so how to protect it from un-authorised access

Comment: that a completely different question, but the are private docker repos, obviously

Comment: got that.Docker hub has option for private repository too.